# How to replace Leatherback Baloth in the post-Zendikar environment in a deck of this type?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

Artifacts

```
2x Birthing Pod
```

Creatures

```
2x Thrun, the Last Troll
4x Acidic Slime
4x Cudgel Troll
3x Dungrove Elder
2x Elvish Archdruid
2x Garruk's Companion
4x Llanowar Elves
2x Primeval Titan
```

Land

```
22x Forest
```

Spells

```
2x Genesis Wave
2x Green Sun's Zenith
2x Lead the Stampede
2x Beast Within
2x Hunter's Insight
3x Rampant Growth
```

Since Zendikar/M11 rotates out I did not include  Leatherback Baloth into my deck, do you have some ideas for replacing it?

Comment: @downvoter -> Care to add a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming you're happy with how the deck was working up to now, the most important thing is to preserve the mana curve.  That is made extra important of course by the use of birthing pod.  Once you constrain to 3-cost green-only creatures, the list of options in standard is quite manageable.  Especially considering you can exclude the infect creatures.

http://magiccards.info/query?q=t%3A%22creature%22+%28c%3Ac+or+c%21g%29+cmc%3D3+f%3Astandard&s=cname&v=card&p=1

I would say a fourth Dungrove Elder is an obvious recommendation.  I also like Sylvok Replica a lot for this deck.  The option to use him as an artifact removal is great, and he still finds Thrun for you if your opponent has no artifacts.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a Dungrove Elder, but I don't know why Sylvok Replica would help me since I got 4 acidic slimes.

Comment: That link is nice. I think I will try Ezuri and consider a some more elves. By the way: I don't want to start another question for this but one other card which is hard to replace is sylvan ranger. I checked the currently legal cards but I haven't find a replacement which costs 1-3 mana. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah. Something good: http://magiccards.info/mbs/en/95.html

Comment: I find the slime is better used blowing up lands to keep your opponent off one of their colors.  A turn 3 slime (via elf ramp) blowing up someone's only land of a particular color can be brutal.  Having an easily tutored alternate way to kill swords and curses later means you don't have to second guess doing it.

Comment: Yep, the best opening hand contains a mana-turbo elf, a Llanovar elf and a slime among 2+ lands.

Comment: How does Sylvok Replica find Thrun if my opponent has no artifacts?

Comment: @Adam Arold by sacrificing it to the birthing pod.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious tack, after a rotation, is to look at cards that will be rotating in that may fill the hole left by the cards rotating out.  In the 3cc range for a mono green deck, this card immediately caught my eye:

> Splinterfright (2G)
>
> Trample.  Splinterfright's power and toughness are each equal to the
>   number of creature cards in your graveyard. At the beginning of your
>   upkeep, put the top two cards of your library into your graveyard.

Alternatively, this doesn't look too bad in a green deck packing a lot of creatures, though it would probably work better with lots of tramplers (4 Garruk's Companions would be a good start):

> Elder of Laurels (2G)
>
> 2/3.  3G: Target creature gets +X/+X until end of turn, where X is the
>   number of creatures you control.

Not in the 3cc slot, sadly, but this card looks like the poster child for mono green horde decks in the new set:

> Essence of the Wild (3GGG):
>
> 6/6.  Creatures you control enter the battlefield as a copy of Essence
>   of the Wild.

Unfortunately all of these are rares or mythics, but it's that or go werewolves basically...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Splinterfright won't work for me since I don't have graveyard-messing cards. Elder of Laurels looks mutch better.

Comment: Splinterfright works in any deck with a lot of creatures, because either your creatures stay alive (in which case they are beating down, and killing, your opponent) or else they die, in which case you play the pumped up Splinterfright.  The big problem of a "horde deck" is often mass removal.  Splinterfright is a great play the turn after your opponent has wiped the board for the second time with a Day of Judgment or whatever... you untap and play a cheap 9/9 Trampler!

Comment: A significant amount of my creatures are hexproof and/or regeneratable so I don't think I will have any problems with mass removal.

Comment: Er, hexproof doesn't usually do much to combat mass removal.  But whatever you think!

Comment: You can't cast a spell on a hexproof creature. If the spell says destroy all creatures my hexproof creatures won't be destroyed.

Comment: @edem hexproof only prevents spells from targeting that creature. Spells that say "do x to *all* creatures" don't target, so therefore hexproof does not protect them, nor does shroud.